# Terminology for asserting truth of equality/inequality based on symbolic equalities/inequalities

Tags: inequality, terminology, systems-of-equations

This may seem silly, but I am curious about algorithms used to computationally assert the truthiness (true, false, or unknown) of symbolic statements subject to a set of inequality constraints, for instance 
\begin{align*}
\text{Constraints}: \\
a &< b \\
b &=c \\
c &= d \\
d &< e \\
\text{Assert whether}: \\
a &< e \\
\text{Returns}: \\
&\text{true}
\end{align*}

I can't help but think that there exist computational algorithms to solve such systems, but I can't find any info on them because I cannot accurately describe such a problem in mathematical terms.

Comment: If your equalities and inequalities are linear (as in your case), then you can use [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) to solve it. Normally you use that tool to minimize or maximize some linear function over a polytope, but you can check if all the extreme points satisfy your assertion, and that would be your answer (or you can add its negation to the constraints and check for satisfiability).

Comment: Also, for a collection of a simple rules like $x \gtreqless y$, you could construct a graph of inequalities which can be used to obtain an answer easier and faster.